Drupal 10 image upload AJAX error with status code 200
Weirdly, I'm getting an AJAX HTTP Error with Drupal 10 when trying to upload an image into a custom node type via Edit functionality.
Here's the error:
[
    {
        "command": "settings",
        "settings": {
            "ajaxPageState": {
                "theme": "claro",
                "theme_token": "M3TQBj9mOsosDYzhHjcCpfd0JwNhnzGrWTiGFD_EG7s",
                "libraries": "eJyNVNGS2yAM_CECT_2A9ubuqTP9BI-MZZsEgw-JXHJfX-E4ThynnbzYYncRIC1AM7hQcYy-hmTmv-aEqOCflO7jEZMLjIHXsooQku3N5ffAlT8tiZyNQdWuq0Y3orkGyh6wcRzTD1PypwBeL5D2ELoM3VNVk_J4L35Fo21s8JeP9vCSGoexB3L0krjnwb-HzoWXdqvd8OK5NEPtRekhRSNforNu3YLM8gDHnQhpRjsfa_A74rN3oZvBIIfftTENSlrBeOIM_jr_huxkxoH-L5l7KqKE5rZT8K4LQzHJI5E5loVhw9SlGZ85Mj4yfUzuW5YE_3uq6Zp1oXmyTtn6FqONbgRi_Ehx-NO2zm6SJxzE8B9PN0x9_JocRBsm5mTxXUZTyR_IEa0D_9ZDAiud3szmBIE8sIuBNIYLPVdeZrgj7m6nWzriPYyEK7CRZWKnYQ-nFU4MjLSCJmc1CbotmpBG2Ykse-EWe-4_MyZx4MVGwoRSJu--UYk5yhaveeahah36pupSzKMpM1bAxRWSW08oIati7muOyejyEcEdJCPV-gil0NXkILMeqrKw41t5lTBizp7reDJ3sSp3YrlDEqsRAnqqxMXZ3MV6T_dU5eEcM5N5gmlLRcv9NW-JJ6BcA_Plmk5OOWIaHFFpd1WfKznSMF3Q4jolJktsMy-9m8eqXMClTxKrh-f6cayRLIz4s7zLKtOtiiWenmT6C0xUV2M"
            },
            "ajax": {
                "edit-field-image-0-remove-button--XUSHtLBPI6U": {
                    "callback": [
                        "Drupal\\file\\Element\\ManagedFile",
                        "uploadAjaxCallback"
                    ],
                    "wrapper": "ajax-wrapper--ZinswkrYwh4",
                    "effect": "none",
                    "progress": {
                        "type": "throbber",
                        "message": null
                    },
                    "event": "mousedown",
                    "keypress": true,
                    "prevent": "click",
                    "url": "\/en\/node\/600\/edit?element_parents=field_image\/widget\/0\u0026destination=\/en\/admin\/content\u0026ajax_form=1\u0026_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax",
                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                    "dialogType": "ajax",
                    "submit": {
                        "_triggering_element_name": "field_image_0_remove_button",
                        "_triggering_element_value": "Remove"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ajaxTrustedUrl": {
                "\/en\/node\/600\/edit?element_parents=field_image\/widget\/0\u0026destination=\/en\/admin\/content\u0026ajax_form=1\u0026_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax": true
            },
            "pluralDelimiter": "\u0003",
            "user": {
                "uid": "1",
                "permissionsHash": "fe66cae0a3f59fc98d64b4cb35554c298ed4428a82ecef9b060b4d1806947018"
            }
        },
        "merge": true
    },
    {
        "command": "add_css",
        "data": [
            {
                "rel": "stylesheet",
                "media": "all",
                "href": "\/sites\/default\/files\/css\/css_o2TKLd_uBO46SALOh09xozXkX50NHET_xxSiTsljnQs.css?delta=0\u0026language=en\u0026theme=claro\u0026include=eJxLzkksytdPzkksLq7US8vMSQUAO5EGng\u0026exclude=eJyNVFGS2yAMvRCBrx6g3dn96kyP4JGxYpNg8CKRTfb0FY7jxHbayRfiPSEJ6QE0vQsVx-hrSGZaNSdEBf-kdBdPmFxgDLx0qwgh2c5clxVXVpoDORuDql1bDW5AczOUPWLjOKYfpsRPAbyeIe0htBnap15NysOj8ys-2sYGf_lojy95Yz90QI5ecu649--hdeGlarXrX7yXZqi9eHpI0UxkgNNOYJrQ1sca_I744l1oJzDIVXf7mHoljWc8cwZ_O39HdnLiSP93mSYoTgnNvS7wrg19kcSayBxLYtgwdWn9Z46Ma6aLyX1LSvC_xw4uWReaJ3lK6VuMNn4DEONHiv2f_d7ZTfCEvcj742nB1MWvUS-0YWJOFt9lN7Z8RQ5oHfi3DhJYmevmNCcI5IFdDKQxXOmp83LCnXB3v908Ee9hIFyAjaSJrYYDnBc4MTDSAhp11CRot2hCGqQSSXvlZjEePjOmi55kJEwobfLuG5WIo5R4izNt1d6hb6o2xTyYcmIBXFUhsfWIErLQfq6l2AUQhwdIdmrvI5RGV6OCzHKrSmLH9_YqYUScHdfxbB5sVd7E_IbEVgME9FSJirN5sPWBHqnKwyVmJvME05aKL3e3uMUegfIMzJdrWrnlgKl3RGXcVX2p5Er9-ECL6pSILLHNPM9u2qvyAOc5ia1Wn_N6r5EsDPiz_MIq072LxR4_YPoLGwtQmg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "update_build_id",
        "old": "form-jq0fzIj2z48WjPSsRfkJeoTmGDaYjqvXhuyg8jXX_Ic",
        "new": "form-EdRrdxlgzesrZCG1dOXsKQH3pzRaKBCqECoPv4CXaRw"
    },
    {
        "command": "insert",
        "method": "replaceWith",
        "selector": null,
        "data": "\u003Cdiv id=\u0022ajax-wrapper--ZinswkrYwh4\u0022\u003E\u003Cdetails open class=\u0022claro-details\u0022\u003E    \u003Csummary role=\u0022button\u0022 aria-expanded=\u0022true\u0022 class=\u0022claro-details__summary\u0022\u003EPartner Image\u003C\/summary\u003E\u003Cdiv class=\u0022claro-details__wrapper details-wrapper\u0022\u003E\n    \n      \u003Cdiv class=\u0022js-form-item form-item js-form-type-managed-file form-type--managed-file js-form-item-field-image-0 form-item--field-image-0 form-item--no-label\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-field-image-0-upload--aoS4kiGILDo\u0022 id=\u0022edit-field-image-0--TKYCNmAezUk--label\u0022 class=\u0022form-item__label visually-hidden\u0022\u003EPartner Image\u003C\/label\u003E\n        \u003Cdiv class=\u0022image-widget js-form-managed-file form-managed-file form-managed-file--image is-single no-upload has-value has-meta\u0022\u003E\n  \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-managed-file__main\u0022\u003E\n    \n\u003Cspan data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-field-image-0-file-470-filename\u0022 class=\u0022file file--mime-image-png file--image\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0022\/sites\/default\/files\/2024-04\/Dentons-Logo-RGB-Dentons-Purple-300_3.png\u0022 type=\u0022image\/png\u0022\u003EDentons-Logo-RGB-Dentons-Purple-300_3.png\u003C\/a\u003E \u003Cspan class=\u0022file__size\u0022\u003E(23.11 KB)\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/span\u003E\n\n    \u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-field-image-0-remove-button\u0022 formnovalidate=\u0022formnovalidate\u0022 class=\u0022button--extrasmall remove-button button js-form-submit form-submit\u0022 type=\u0022submit\u0022 id=\u0022edit-field-image-0-remove-button--XUSHtLBPI6U\u0022 name=\u0022field_image_0_remove_button\u0022 value=\u0022Remove\u0022\/\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-managed-file__meta-wrapper\u0022\u003E\n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-managed-file__meta\u0022\u003E\n              \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-managed-file__image-preview image-preview\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv class=\u0022image-preview__img-wrapper\u0022\u003E\n            \u003Cimg data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-field-image-0-preview\u0022 src=\u0022\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/thumbnail\/public\/2024-04\/Dentons-Logo-RGB-Dentons-Purple-300_3.png?itok=2KpHfTn3\u0022 width=\u0022100\u0022 height=\u002226\u0022 alt=\u0022\u0022 loading=\u0022lazy\u0022 typeof=\u0022foaf:Image\u0022 class=\u0022image-style-thumbnail\u0022 \/\u003E\n\n\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n        \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \n              \u003Cdiv class=\u0022form-managed-file__meta-items\u0022\u003E\n          \n                    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022js-form-item form-item js-form-type-textfield form-type--textfield js-form-item-field-image-0-alt form-item--field-image-0-alt\u0022\u003E\n      \u003Clabel for=\u0022edit-field-image-0-alt--mb1G4bns59U\u0022 class=\u0022form-item__label js-form-required form-required\u0022\u003EAlternative text\u003C\/label\u003E\n        \u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-field-image-0-alt\u0022 aria-describedby=\u0022edit-field-image-0-alt--mb1G4bns59U--description\u0022 type=\u0022text\u0022 id=\u0022edit-field-image-0-alt--mb1G4bns59U\u0022 name=\u0022field_image[0][alt]\u0022 value=\u0022\u0022 size=\u002260\u0022 maxlength=\u0022512\u0022 class=\u0022form-text required form-element form-element--type-text form-element--api-textfield\u0022 required=\u0022required\u0022 aria-required=\u0022true\u0022\/\u003E\n            \u003Cdiv id=\u0022edit-field-image-0-alt--mb1G4bns59U--description\u0022 class=\u0022form-item__description\u0022\u003E\n      Short description of the image used by screen readers and displayed when the image is not loaded. This is important for accessibility.\n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\n          \n        \u003C\/div\u003E\n          \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \n    \u003Cinput data-drupal-selector=\u0022edit-field-image-0-fids\u0022 type=\u0022hidden\u0022 name=\u0022field_image[0][fids]\u0022 value=\u0022470\u0022\/\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E\n\n        \u003C\/div\u003E\n  \u003C\/div\u003E\n\u003C\/details\u003E\n\u003C\/div\u003E",
        "settings": nul

I have no idea how to debug this or how to fix the error.
It only happens on the dev server environment, and not on local Docksal environment

do you have any logs or any error messages. And check your folder permission to the files folder.

@ViswanathPolaki, no logs or error messages related to this error, neither in Drupal logs, nor in Apache access/error logs.
Obviously, checked folder permissions and they are set correctly to write

That's the whole point - there's nothing in the server logs, no error messages except the one in the console and another on the page saying "Oops, something went wrong. Check Javascript console for more details".
Obviously, all file permissions are correct

which browser are you using, can you check with a different browser like firefox and check if the functionality its working or not.

@ViswanathPolaki I'm getting same error both with Chrome and Firefox on Linux

For those who encounter the similar problem, this was finally resolved by upgrading the server from Debian 8 to Debian 11. Really strange...
